# Distinct error java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to model class

Tags: hibernate, distinct

I want to make distinct query in hibernate
here is my DaoImpl

```
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<ModelNilai> getListNilaiAwal(Integer page, Integer id, Integer idm) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<ModelNilai> list = new ArrayList<ModelNilai>();
        Disjunction dis = Restrictions.disjunction();

        dis.add(Restrictions.eq("mahasiswa.id", id));


        Criteria c = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ModelNilai.class);

        c.createAlias("makul","m");

        c.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));
        c.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("m.id")));
        c.add(dis);

        if(page!=null){
            c.setFirstResult((page-1)*LISTSIZE);
        }

        /*Mengurutkan data yang dipilih berdasar id secara Descending*/
        c.addOrder(Order.desc("id"));

        /*Menentukan jumlah baris data dari tabel yang di pilih*/
        c.setMaxResults(LISTSIZE);

        list.addAll(c.list());

        if(page==null){
            setTotalPage(c);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

here my ModelNilai

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_makul")
    private ModelMakul makul;
```

ModelMakul

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="makul",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JsonIgnore
        private Set<ModelNilai> nilai;
```

When i run,,,
it make this query

```
    Hibernate: select distinct m1_.id_makul as y0_ from tbl_nilai this_ inner join tbl_makul m1_ on this_.id_makul=m1_.id_makul where (this_.id_mhs=?) order by this_.id_nilai desc limit ?
Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from tbl_nilai this_ inner join tbl_makul m1_ on this_.id_makul=m1_.id_makul where (this_.id_mhs=?) order by this_.id_nilai desc limit ?
```

and error happen
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to id.ac.undip.mlearning.model.ModelNilai

where i go wrong? I think the query is right, but why it always give me that error?
please help,,

Answer (score 0):

```
c.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("m.id")));
```

tells hibernate to return a list of ids which will be `List<Integer>`. You are trying to add the result to a `List<ModelNilai>`.

Comment: thanks,,, i know what wrong now,,
can you tell me how to do distinct projection?